# Почему функция возвращает false?

Tags: javascript

почему функция возращает false? если в массиве есть такой аргумент

```js
let y = [10, 3, 6, 9, 15, 30]

function test(x, y) {
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (x == y[i]) {
      console.log(true)
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log(false)
      return false;
    }
  }
}

test(3, y)
```

Comment: Потому что 3 ≠ 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что после `return` функцию сразу завершается. В вашем случае первый элемент это `10` и он не равен `3` и функцию возвращает `false`.

Перенесите содержимое `else` за цикл `for`.

```js
let y = [10, 3, 6, 9, 15, 30]

function test(x,y) {
    for(let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        if (x == y[i]) {
            console.log(true);
            return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}

test(3, y);
```

Comment: ответ как принятый могу ставить через 5 мин